# to provide the means to

Tags: articles, idioms, definite-article

Is the phrase "to provide the means to" idiomatic in English? I often see the phrase in cases where, I think, "the means" are/is not definite. For example:

> 1) 'Lamp holder' or 'socket' means a device which holds the lamp in
>   position, usually by having the cap inserted in it, in which case it
>   also provides **the means** of connecting the lamp to the electric
>   supply.
>
> 2) Although the UN doesn't make laws, it provides **the means** to help
>   resolve international conflicts and formulate policies on matters
>   affecting each and every one of us.

Shouldn't it be "a means" or "means"?

Comment: Idiomatically, [we usually](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=provides+the+means+to%2Cprovides+a+means+to%2Cprovides+a+way+to%2Cprovides+the+way+to&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprovides%20the%20means%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprovides%20a%20means%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprovides%20a%20way%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprovides%20the%20way%20to%3B%2Cc0) say *provides **a way** to...*. Almost never ***the** way*, but both articles are used about equally with the (less common) form ***the / a means to...***

Answer (score 1):

> Is the phrase "to provide the means to" idiomatic in English?

Yes, either with *to* or *for* is very idiomatic.

> I often see the phrase in cases where, I think, "the means" are/is not definite.

"Definite" simply means the speaker/writer needs you to know the answer to the question *which means?*

"Indefinite" means this speaker/writer doesn't care about you knowing the answer to that question.

> 'Lamp holder' or 'socket' means a device which holds the lamp in position, usually by having the cap inserted in it, in which case it also provides the means of connecting the lamp to the electric supply.

Which are the means of connecting the lamp to the electric supply?  The lamp holder or socket.  Writer/speaker expects you to understand that.  If the writer/speaker is teaching you about how the lamp works, or training you, etc. that would be one possible reason why.

> 'Lamp holder' or 'socket' means a device which holds the lamp in position, usually by having the cap inserted in it, in which case it also provides a means of connecting the lamp to the electric supply.

The lamp holder or socket is still *a* means of connecting the lamp, but the question "which means is being used" doesn't matter.  This is implying that other means are possible (perhaps it can get connected another way), or that connecting the lamp to the electric supply is not a primary concern (maybe the lamp gets power by a battery).

Comment: So in the UN example the "the" means that the UN is itself the means to help resolve international conflicts?